# Display gridview like structure in R?

Tags: r, gridview, shiny

I have calculated List of dataframe like below:

```
[[1]]
        COUNTRY     Freq percen
1        A          8    100
2        B          0      0
3        C          0      0

[[2]]
        TYPE  Freq percen
1       ABC    4   50.0
2       DEF    2   25.0
3       XYZ    1   12.5
4       PQR    1   12.5
...
```

I have to display the above data in some structured way,
So i am thinking best way to display above can be:

```
    COUNTRY             TYPE        ...
LEVEL   percen      LEVEL   percen
A       100         ABC     50.0
B       0           DEF     25.0
C       0           XYZ     12.5
                    PQR     12.5
```

There are varied length of list with entries like above i have to show.

I am not sure how to proceed with this type of data to display in R.
Any help or better way to show above kind of data will be good for me.

Comment: You might want to check out the [listviewer package](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/listviewer).

Comment: @TravisHinkelman looks very promising for this, i will update if i found any solution using above. Thanks:)

Comment: If the data needs to be accessed easily but does not need to be "visible", you can also use nested data frames. But I suspect that it does not match your "gridview" requirement... Nested data frames are a nice way to put data frames of various sizes within one familiar structure (the data frame in which they are nested).

Comment: @prosoitos even if it's dataframe under dataframe or like right now dataframe under list, difference will be by accessibility only, what i intend to ask is how to make it display easier, because in current view there's a lot of scroll and can't have overview of whole data. I am thinking towards now to better visualize using stacked barplot or something,, I will update the final solution what i will use for sure here, and Thanks for writing.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below approach to better visualize the above kind of data:

First convert the list of dataframe into single dataframe like below::

```
Columns     Levels  Percent
----------------------------
LEVEL       ABC     50.0
LEVEL       DEF     25.0
LEVEL       XYZ     12.5
LEVEL       PQR     12.5
COUNTRY     A       100.0
COUNTRY     B       0.0
COUNTRY     C       0.0
```

Then used ggplot 'Faceting Graph' approach to visualize each column and Levels inside of that.
[image: Proposed]

If anyone interested in graph code it's like below:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=percent, x=levels, color=levels,fill=levels)) + 
geom_bar( stat="identity", position = "dodge") +    
facet_wrap(~column, scales="free_x",ncol =4) +
theme(legend.position="none")
```

in above *scales="free_x"* is very important as i dont want the levels of other Columns also to be include in my plot.